# Manage and Cache Connection while using mongoose in AWS lambda and serverless

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-lambda

I have deployed one backend app (Node Js/ Express) in AWS lambda using serverless.

In db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODBURL , {
    useNewUrlParser : true
})
```

In app.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/db')

const app = express()

// ...Rest code goes here
```

In handler.js

```
'use strict';
const app = require('./app')
const serverless = require('serverless-http')

module.exports.hello = serverless(app)
```

This is how I have structured my code. But how to manage and cache monogoose connections in this type code structure so that the lambda wont create new connection each time its invoked.

I have tried reading mongoose connection guide while using AWS lambda. But I am not able follow along with this kind of code structure

Answer (score 1):

Update your db.js with this code. then call dbConnect() where you want the connection to happen. According to aws I think it should be outside of your handlers export statement. But because we are reusing existing connection here, i don't see why we can't also call dbConnect() in everyfiles that make database calls, just in case the existing connection is stale.
Please leave a comment if it works in your case, or face any other issues.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI

if (!MONGO_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable!!'
  )
}

let cached = global.mongoose

const dbConnect = async () => {
  if (cached && cached.conn && cached.conn.readyState === 1) {
    return cached.conn
  }
  // Close the existing connection if it exist but is stale.
  if (cached && cached.conn) {
    await cached.conn.close()
  }

  const opts = {
    //bufferCommands: false,
    // useNewUrlParser: true, 
    //basically add the required options here.
  }

  cached.conn = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, opts)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Database connected!')
      return mongoose.connection
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Failed to connect to the database:', error)
      throw error
    })

  return cached.conn
};

module.exports = dbConnect
```